# What's the best term for "geographical level"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm creating an interface where users can choose which geographical level to report on. I.e., they're choosing between "Country", "State", and "City". Is there a better term than "level" to describe these choices?

UPDATE: as noted in the comments below, the "geographical" part of this label will actually be "Geo" because that's a standard term in online advertising, FWIW. So I'm looking for something better than "Geo Level", and probably something that tends toward the colloquial, rather than the formal or technical.

Comment: Those are political entities, for the most part; they have geographical boundaries, but there's more than geography involved. So you might want to just have users choose from a chart and not try to describe the options too closely. Then, if the chart is oriented vertically, the [UP/DOWN metaphoric notion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf) of _level_ refers naturally, without having to be pointed out unnecessarily.

Comment: @JohnLawler users will be selecting from "Country", "State" & "DMA"[1]. Given the context (an ad tech reporting ui), I'm fairly certain that those words will be more than enough for users to understand what they mean. Nonetheless, I want to find the best label possible. I don't think a chart squished into the space would be more helpful. [1] "Designated Market Area", which roughly corresponds to a city and the region around it.

Comment: Technically, these are hierarchical levels, so that shouldn't be an issue. It's calling them "geographical" that's problematic, since it's scale and granularity, not geography per se that's at issue.

Comment: Can you just use a simple term like *Location* or *Place*?

Comment: @JohnLawler if it helps, I'm actually calling them "geo" not "geographical", since that's the industry standard term for this stuff. :)

Comment: @JLG I think those would make sense if they were selecting a specific one, e.g. "San Francisco", not a category.

Comment: Industry standards are always useful. The only problem is there are so many to choose from.

Comment: It would be helpful to identify the industry.

Comment: @MarkBeadles online advertising. (Added it to the update.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I wound up sticking with "Geo Level" for the moment.

Answer (score 6):

These are often called **divisions** or **subdivisions**, whether [geopolitical, geographical, or administrative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_division).

Comment: I think division is a bit too techie, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Scale" is the best word I can think of: "A proportion used in determining the dimensional relationship of a representation to that which it represents." (Reference: AH)

Answer (score 2):

The first word I thought of was *granularity*, since that is what we use in the GIS industry.

However, you mention you are looking for something less technical, so I'd suggest *[extent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extent?s=t)*. The geographic *extent* describes the degree to which an area is covered, so it would seem to fit your requirement.

If you wanted something very colloquial, you could use *zoom*.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *layer*, which implies (to me, at least) that the user can delve deeper into or back between the different views (i.e. a city is a deeper *layer* of the view than a state, which is a deeper *layer* than a country, etc.). "Geo Layer" sounds pretty cool to me.

Answer (score 0):

> geographical level to report on ...

I might call this *focus* or perhaps, *geographical focus*.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help if you just specify a "Location" in the User Interface and then provide Combo Box(es) for them to choose a Country, State or a City? When it comes to designing pages where the comfort level of each user varies.... i personally feel it would be better to use familiar words. Not that there is anything complicated about "geographical level" ... but as far as i know "Location" is more frequent.

Comment: They aren't choosing a specific location. They're choosing a category of location.